# Issue with how LinkedIn is converting the open graph picture

Tags: linkedin-api, facebook-opengraph

I'm running into an issue where linkedin seems to be distorting the colors of images. In the metatags of my site I'm adding the meta tag og:image and add a link for the image that I want linkedin to use in shares.

But once they cache and convert it, the images are totally distorted.

For example:
- the photo I've added as og:image : http://storage.prezly.com/ee/5a7e10a54211e4a13c7b396195f7d6/DPC_8776-1.jpg
- How it is displayed on linkedin: 
https://media.licdn.com/media-proxy/ext?w=180&h=110&f=c&hash=4PlxYl4xyM3Hy6nYu5nAtQmVjuI%3D&ora=1%2CaFBCTXdkRmpGL2lvQUFBPQ%2CxAVta9Er0UK-nAkbxRlv8LyEt0OpqkRISM3ZBy-kCiL_-9XRZXPreMaKfeOgpw4RKi8IlgU7ermvFDb-ZvPPRILoetpsiom_ZMc

Anyone an idea if I can do something on my end to solve this?

Comment: Can you modify your post and include a link to the original shared page so we can inspect the OG tags and look for anything else that might be an issue?

Answer (score 0):

The image manipulation library that LinkedIn currently uses has issues with JPEGs that have transparency information encoded within them.  For the moment, the only solution to this problem is to ensure your pictures are not saved with an RGBA colour-space, as the "A" channel in there is what's responsible for that purple-ish shift in the colour space.

If your image is saved in a standard RGB formatted JPEG, or as a PNG, you should have no problems with the image.

Note that LinkedIn also has a week-long cache, so if you change the file on your end, it could take up to one week before the cached copy is invalidated and the image is re-indexed.